# Plastic SCM server access outside home network

Tags: plasticscm

I have installed Plastic SCM server in one of my PCs at home (Windows 7 - Home Prem). The server is accessible from the clients residing inside my home network. It is resolved using the home network PC name as the server address / visible name.

However, I would like to be able to have access to the server from outside the home network. Ideally, I would like to use the IP that has been assigned to the PC, by the ISP, where the server resides. I can deal with the intermittent IP address changes. The PC is just a regular, personal use PC (i.e. not configured as a server).

A couple of questions: Is this possible to access Plastic SCM server from outside the home network using the IP address that the ISP assigns to the PC where PSCM-Server resides?

Second, the server config tool automatically displays as the visible name of the PC, the name assigned in the home network. It does not allow me to enter an IP address. If the answer to the first question is yes, how can I enter the desired IP address?

Are there any configurations that must be in place on Windows 7 (Home Premium), perhaps?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Plastic SCM servers listens in two ports: a SSL one and an plain TCP one. I'd strongly recommend you to set up an SSL connection if you're going to open up the port on the internet.

http://codicesoftware.blogspot.com/2010/08/ssl-enabled-plastic-connections-reborn.html

In order to configure your PC:

- As you pointed you'll need to redirect the traffic from your router to your PC
- The "redirection" must go from a public port to the Plastic SCM port (the TCP or the SSL ones)
- Your PC should have the firewall configured to allow incoming traffic to the Plastic SCM port

Regarding your question about "the server configuration": no, it just shows you the name, you can't set the IP since it simply takes the IP/name from your server. It wouldn't work otherwise, unless you mean you've a multi-IP machine. Is that the case? Do you have more than one network card in your PC? If that's the case, there's a way to specify where to listen, but let's confirm first your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making the assumption that you are using Plastic 4.x (I don't know how similar the 3.x version is to this)

The answer to your first question is YES.  I frequently connect to my home plastic server from my work machine to view or grab projects/tools that I need.

Your second question is not technically accurate - what you need is the CLIENT tool to access your server IP address - and that IS possible.

To answer your final question - how to do it: start the Client Configuration tool on this "external" PC.
On the third page of the CLIENT configuration tool, it asks for the Plasti SCM server selection - it gives you an entry for the server address, and an entry for the port.

You most likely have set up the username/password access type on the server, but you could also have used Local users - be sure to select the appropriate log-in type you configured your server for on the final page.

Your only other consideration is the Firewall on Win7 (and as pointed out by Pablo, your router config to 'point' to your server machine on the desired ports (8087/8088) need to be forwarded) must allow those ports to be accessed.  (I believe 3.x used different ports)